# PHP foreach varable outside loop not updated

Tags: php, variables, foreach

Can someone help me understand the issue I am having. It's a  bug in some open source api I am trying to fix.

I have simple  function that supposed to  return array. But returns empty array
$this  - is an object and it's correct

```
public function toArray($minimized = false) {
    $array = [];

    foreach($this->list as $item) {
        $item->updateBeanProperties();
        $array[] = $item->toArray($minimized);
       // here print_r($array) gives correct result
    }
      // here print_r($array) gives empty array 
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: I think this is local vs. global scope issue with the $array variable. What happens if you remove `$array = [];`?

Comment: can you add a sample of what you want and what you got?

Comment: @RobMoll PHP scope is by function, both uses of `$array` are in the same function.